# Learning SSIS 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I would like to learn SSIS 2008. can any one guide me to get ebbok to learn SSIS 2008?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [Designing and Implementing Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms141767%28v=sql.105%29)
- [SSIS tutorials on JumpstartTV](https://web.archive.org/web/20101015055426/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/mattm/archive/2007/06/12/ssis-tutorials-on-jumpstarttv.aspx)
- SSIS Tutorial: [SQL Server 2005 Integration Services Tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20130913094107/http://www.accelebrate.com/sql_training/ssis_tutorial.htm)
- [SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS)](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/200/sql-server-integration-services-ssis-tutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

The "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Integration Services problem-design-solution" book on Wrox Press, ISBN 978-0-470-52576-0 is pretty good.

The "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Integration Services" book on Wrox Press, ISBN 978-0-470-24795-2 is all right.

Also, there are SSIS 2008 training videos on AppDev that are a great place to start if you've never worked with SSIS before.